# OpenVPN gateway through OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn, gateway

I'm trying to setup an OpenVPN access for clients through a server A I own. But I want these clients to connect to another OpenVPN server on an host B, configured as client on A.

```
           OVPN                OVPN
[Client] -------> [Server A] -------> [Host B]
  tun0           tun0 -- tun1
10.8.0.2     10.8.0.1 -- 10.9.0.2     10.9.0.1
```

Forwarding is allowed between the `tun0` and `tun1` interfaces. My initial idea was to push to the client the route to access `10.9.0.1`, and use this address as a gateway, which would allow the clients to use services directly on `10.8.0.1` as well as access the world through the host B.

However, OpenVPN on the client doesn't seem to run the necessary `ip route add ...` commands if I only do the following so it doesn't seem as easy:

```
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "route 10.9.0.1 255.255.255.255 10.8.0.1"
push "route-gateway 10.9.0.1"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
```

Thanks for your help.